# Motion Bubble Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, kendo-ui

I have requirement of bubble chart as follow:-

- Bubble Chart having the motion bubble.
- Bubble leaves the trails in fade color.
- Bubble motion control with navigation button in the
  bottom of the chart  When bubble navigate to any position that should
  appear in dark color.

[image]
Scenario:

> Y-axis having population in lakh and X-axis have months. Once the
>   chart initialize the bubble move from  left to right according to
>   input figure (i.e.. Population, month). As show in the figure chart
>   have navigation button from where bubble can be navigate to other
>   faded bubbles. Selected bubble through navigation will always
>   highlighted in dark colour.  In our case, as shown in figure Oct month
>   bubble is a selected with dark highlighted colour where others are
>   faded

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this motion chart: http://www.amcharts.com/inspiration/motion-chart/

To make trails, you'll have to modify it a bit, but it's a good thing to start.